# jQuery handle a href on clicking an anchor element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm using:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control searchValue">
<a href="#" class="btn btn-default searchButton">Search</a>
```

in order to perform search. When user clicks on search, jQuery has to get the value of the input and then redirect user to the page itself + "?search=valueInInput" in order to perform search in PHP by using GET value in URL.

For this, I used:

```
$(".searchButton").on("click", function($this){
    var url = location.host + "/index.php?search=" + $(".searchValue").val();
    $(".searchButton").attr("href", url)
 });
```

The problem is that user is never redirected to the url, but I didn't put any `return false` or `preventDefault`, why?

How to change this in order to perform the search?

Comment: get rid of `location.host` since you don't have `protocol` prefix for it. Should work if element exists when code is run

Comment: Have you considered changing your code to post the form.  with a single search field your solution works, but with increased complexity the form submit pays dividends.  There is also an onsubmit method that can be used to inject validation logic.

Comment: @GlennFerie: yes you have reason, I should

Comment: @GlennFerrie : I finaly used your solution, it doesn't use jQuery and more easy to maintain

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
$(".searchButton").on("click", function(){
        var url = "/index.php?search=" + $(".searchValue").val();
        $(".searchButton").attr("href", url)
     });
```

I removed $this and location.host.

Comment: thanks. I've already testes this but t looks like it doesn't reload the page :-/ URL doesn't change and there is no GET var detected by PHP neither

Comment: not true, can change the href within click event handler and works fine...assuming provide valid url.  http://jsfiddle.net/xerqt0uu/

Comment: I've updated my answer. This should work. charlietfl is correct.

Comment: I've set valid response because it respond to the question but for people who wants to use minimum of jquery/js, I've made response too that use pure HTML as @GlennFerie recommanded

Answer (score 1):

This is the code I finally used. I think this is better to maintain without JS and it's more clean...

```
<form action="index.php" method="GET">
                <div class="form-group">
                                <input name="search" id="search" type="text" class="form-control searchValue" value="qsdfdf">                                
                </div> 
                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Recherche</button>
                </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since it is the same page that you have to redirect to it, so you don't need to regard the file name in the URL. Also you may use the location property of the window object:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".searchButton").click(function(){
     q = $(".searchValue").val();
      window.location = "?search="+q
  });

});
```

Checkout this [DEMO](http://jsbin.com/rehide/1/)